# SharePoint 2010 - Change table row /cell hover effect

Tags: sharepoint-2010

In SharePoint 2010 when you hover over a column heading (i.e. to sort) in a list table, you get a hover effect, how can you supress / change this? I can see it uses `OnChildColumn(this)`, so is there a way to modify this - either preventing the effect (e.g. when sorting can't be done on a column), or using a different background image?

Also want to do the same when you hover over a cell in any of the list table's contents.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use jquery for this.

you can find 's4-ctx' class using selector.

Upload transparent image and on hover you can dynamically change image url. Current it points to "/_layouts/images/ecbarw.png".

Let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: The s4-ctx is a div in the table header cell after the name of the field and it is the context menu placeholder, not the cell background. Although I may want to change both.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an alternate style sheet that overrides the following from corev4.css:

1. tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh:hover,tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh2:hover
2. anything that uses .s4-ctx-show